# Eclipse ADT Bundle won't create src files and layout files

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

Every time I create a new project, nothing in the src folder shows up. The layout folder is also empty. I have updated my eclipse to the latest ADT and updated the SDK manager but it still will not work for me. I have also tried to download the bundle again but it gives the same error. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution : 
I have been struggling with this issue for 2 days now. Searched through countless posts and countless suggestions.

With the new ADT kit I was selecting "Blank Activity"

This morning I tried "Empty Activity"

This creates the Main activity

Comment: THANK YOU THIS WAS IT! I was doing the same thing before because in the previous versions blank activity made at least an activity with nothing on it. Man thank you dude I really appreciate you answering this despite this being an old question! :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to select an Android Project. Then create an empty project if you want to add your activity and your xml yourself

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to go back to the ADT bundle before this one there are problems right now, here is a place you can download from :

https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321.zip - Windows 7 64 bit
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321.zip - Windows 7 32 bit

I had the same problem like you, its a problem in the new ADT .. install this one until google will fix it in a new version.

Comment: @Meeko actually , you just need to change the " windows " from the link to "mac" , here :
https://dl.google.com/android/adt/22.6.2/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321.zip
Unfortunately, it works only at the 64bit version, so I don't have the 32bit mac link..

Comment: for linux I found only this : 
http://kickass.to/developers-android-tools-t8973279.html
torrent file, for everyone who needs.

Comment: I downloaded the older version but when I try to finalize the project and build it, it gives me this error:



Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'AndroidApp'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

Any idea why?